# RegistrySecurity Access is denied. C#

Tags: c#, security, registry

I'm currently having an issue when writing an app to set permissions on some Legacy keys. Legacy keys are quite locked down and to actually modify them in regedit you have to take ownership and then add yourself with full control. When trying to replicate this in code i cannot get the key for write with the error "Access is denied". Example code:

```
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Administrators", RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
rs.SetOwner(new NTAccount("Administrators"));
return LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(post, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, rs);
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I have also tried OpenSubKey with write access requested and I just cannot get the key.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a solution. You had to open the key with "ChangePermissions" and then change the permission for yourself... THEN re-open the key with full control to change the owner.
Here's how.

```
RegistryKey rk = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey, RegistryKeyPremissionsCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions | RegistryRights.ReadKey);//Get the registry key desired with ChangePermissions Rights.
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Administrator", RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));//Create access rule giving full control to the Administrator user.
rk.SetAccessControl(rs); //Apply the new access rule to this Registry Key.
rk = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey, RegistryKeyPremissionsCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl); // Opens the key again with full control.
rs.SetOwner(new NTAccount("Administrator"));// Set the securitys owner to be Administrator
rk.SetAccessControl(rs);// Set the key with the changed permission so Administrator is now owner.
```

This works for me. Let me know if it works for you :)

Obviously change Administrator to another user if you aren't logged in as administrator or if you need rights for another user.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app with that code are you right-clicking the exe and selecting "Run As Administrator"?

Comment: Hi Steve, I run Visual Studios as administrator so debugging should run as admin? I have also tried run as admin and it does not work still. the Legacy keys are totally locked down with access only to System and Everyone set as read only. I have found a solution and will post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

First must Set a permission with right FULL-ACCESS to subkey

```
RegistryKey rkey = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(_subKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, gistryRights.ChangePermissions);
if (rkey == null)
 throw new Exception("Not Open");
//-------
RegistrySecurity _registrySecurity =new RegistrySecurity();//Or rkey.GetAccessControl();
WindowsIdentity _windowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
RegistryAccessRule _accessRule = new RegistryAccessRule(_windowsIdentity.Name, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);
_registrySecurity.AddAccessRule(_accessRule);
_registrySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, true);
 rkey.SetAccessControl(_registrySecurity);

//--------Now, Set owner

_registrySecurity.SetGroup(new NTAccount("Administrators"));  //This is optional
var SID = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("XXX\\Users");
_registrySecurity.SetOwner(SID);
rkey.SetAccessControl(_registrySecurity);
```

XXX : your account name

Answer (score -1):

```
        RegistryKey rkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Norton\SecurityStatusSDK", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions);
        if (rkey == null)
            throw new Exception("Not Open");
        //-------
        RegistrySecurity _registrySecurity = new RegistrySecurity();//Or rkey.GetAccessControl();
        WindowsIdentity _windowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        RegistryAccessRule _accessRule = new RegistryAccessRule(_windowsIdentity.Name, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);
        _registrySecurity.AddAccessRule(_accessRule);
        _registrySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, true);
        try
        {
            rkey.SetAccessControl(_registrySecurity);// <---"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {

        }

        //--------Now, Set owner

        _registrySecurity.SetGroup(new NTAccount("Administrators"));  //This is optional
        var SID = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("XXX\\Users");
        _registrySecurity.SetOwner(SID);
        rkey.SetAccessControl(_registrySecurity);
```

I installed Norton Internet Security

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (Administrator)

`_subKey = SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Norton`

`rkey.SetAccessControl(_registrySecurity);->`"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."`

Comment: What exactly are you answering with this? I'm sorry I dont follow.