# How to set speaker sound enhancement settings

Tags: c#, windows, audio, cscore

How can I programatically set those sound effects available from the Windows Speaker Settings (Enhancements tab)?

[image: Spearker Properties - Enhancements tab]

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid of that this is not possible. 
See the comment of Maurits on his [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2011/06/13/how-to-enumerate-audio-endpoint-immdevice-properties-on-your-system.aspx).

> Each endpoint has two property stores; the "endpoint property store"
>   displayed above, and the "effects property store."  The endpoint
>   property store is exposed to applications, but the effects property
>   store is limited to:
>
> 1) the audio driver
>
> 2) the audio engine
>
> 3) the Sound control panel.
>
> So only the user can view / change settings in the effects property
>   store, and that only through the Sound control panel.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I got a clear information. I would never figure it out through the Microsoft documentation! However, I was successfully able to enable/disable one of these FX directly through registry manipulation. I'm doing more tests and I'll probably post it as the definitive/alternative answer here.