# Build failed in Visual Studio because of ActiveReports for .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, activereports

I am currently working on an old project, probably around 20 years old. It depended on an old version of ActiveReports software build. When I tried to build the project, the build failed and returns this error:

> Exception occurred creating type
>   'DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Design.Designer, ActiveReports.Design3,
>   Version=5.1.0.158, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff'
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key
>   'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Data Dynamics\SharpGraph for
>   .NET\Windows' is denied.

I have tried many solutions, including installing the licensed software, and editing registry key. But none helped to solve the problem. Is there any other way to solve this, other than installing newer version of ActiveReports for .NET, that is if it exists?

Comment: Is a 32bit or 64bit application? Are you looking in the right registry location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to the registry key '\[KEY\_NAME\]' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029812/access-to-the-registry-key-key-name-is-denied)

Comment: Try running VS as Administrator.

Comment: @Steve It's a 64-bit application. And yes, I looked in the right registry location.

Comment: @TnTinMn I have looked at the link that you posted, but it is not a duplicate of those. My project does not touch nor changes anything on registry key.

Comment: There's no option to 'Run as Admin' on the solution file. I tried to set the VS IDE to 'Run as Admin', however, but now the IDE won't open and neither the solution file.

Comment: I run VS as admin always (for com and IIS) and it works. Just right click and selecting run as admin (suppose you use an admin account) is enough. What do you mean by "IDE won't open and neither the solution file"?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I have to set the VS IDE to 'Run as Admin' in its properties, and then run the solution file by opening it from the IDE itself.

Credits to @TnTinMn for giving the right hint.